# How to access facebook insight datas for consecutive months?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-insights

I'm new to Facebook app development I hope I can get an answer here.

Is that possible to retrieve Facebook insight data for consecutive months?
I tried `end_time=2010-01-01` to `since=2010-01-31` and `period=month` but I got

> The specified date range cannot exceed 3024000 seconds!!

How will I get like 2010-02-01 to 2010-02-28 and 2010-03-01 to 2010-03-31?

I have tried and used lots of examples but I couldn't succeed: How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that has worked for me is very similar to what you are doing, with the difference being that I use the UNIX timestamp for SINCE and UNTIL.

Example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/212686148747689/insights/
page_impressions_by_city_unique/week/?    
access_token=QWERTYUI&since=1315699200&until=1320796800
```

(That's all supposed to be on one line, but it's easier to read it this way, at least for me.)

With this approach, you want to be careful and make sure that the difference between SINCE and UNTIL is not bigger that 90 days. Otherwise, you'll get an error, like so:

```
(#604) The specified date range cannot exceed 7776000 seconds
```

Finally, if you don't have a way of generating the UNIX timestamp automatically, go to a web site like:

http://www.epochconverter.com/

If anyone else has some better insights, please share. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks man i was looking for just like a kick off instead of being ideal thanks shawn

Comment: i made it work  https://graph.facebook.com/pageid/insights?access_token="valid access token"&end_time=2011-10-31&period=month&since=2011-10-01&limit=30 i got json 30 days of  result through this, and  made three request like this by getting 3 consecutive months i've used Json.net to read the stream .